# How are platforms such as mailchimp able to send emails from my account?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mailchimp, nodemailer

I am working on a small service that allows users to send emails in a similar fashion to mailchimp.

How is mailchimp able to send an email from my account without asking me for my password but by simply sending me a confirmation email?

I was wondering if it was possible to replicate this effect using something like nodemailer?

Previously I wrote some code

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'test@gmail.com',
            pass: 'APP_PASS'
        }
        });
        
        var mailOptions = {
            from: 'test2@gmail.com',
            to: 'recipent@gmail.com',
            subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
            text: 'That was easy!'
        };
        
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
        }
        });
```

I was hoping that the "from" part would say for example "test2@gmail.com" but it didn't, for understandable reason.

How do I prompt a user to giving my app access to sending emails from there account or on behalf of their account and then put it into nodemailer, or if nodemailer can not handle this, what could be a similar approach?

Comment: The same way you do. They forge the "from" field. It may be that Gmail doesn't allow users to send mail with a "from" that is anything other than your account or an account you have set up for "Send as".

Comment: @Ouroborus This is an issue with just gmail? If I used another service, would it work?